# parseFloating value using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

how can I solved this script?

**ajax**

```
var jsonVal = {val1 : data.rating}
$('#rt').parseFloat(val(jsonVal.val1)).toFixed(1);
```

**output**

```
<label id="rt" name="rating"></label>
```

I've try with another `var`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try: $('#rt').test(parseFloat((jsonVal.val1)).toFixed(1));

Comment: it doesn't work, empty

Comment: Sorry I thought this is input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('#rt').text(parseFloat(jsonVal.val1).toFixed(1));
```